# Why the mergetool isn't opened when I use --3way on git apply?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict, mergetool, git-apply

Why I fail to use git apply with -3 option :

```
$ git apply --3way /tmp/0001-my-patch.patch
error: patch failed: a.h:9
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to 'a.h' cleanly.
error: patch failed: b.c:6
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to 'b.c' cleanly.
error: patch failed: drivers/Kconfig:1882
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to 'drivers/Kconfig' with conflicts.
U drivers/Kconfig
```

Comment: What is the question here? It's trying the normal apply and then falls back to 3-way, as specified.

Comment: How comes the mergetool didn't open?

Comment: I don't remember how I solved it but, make sure the .gitconfig has the right mergetool configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use \`git mergetool\` with \`git am\` or \`git apply\` or \`patch\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556005/cannot-use-git-mergetool-with-git-am-or-git-apply-or-patch)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `git apply`:

> --3way
>   When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge

It looks like 3way will be ignored if the patch applies cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to configure `diffmerge` as your mergetool [taken from [here]](http://adventuresincoding.com/2010/04/how-to-setup-git-to-use-diffmerge):

```
git config --global merge.tool diffmerge

git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge --merge
--result=\$MERGED \$LOCAL \$BASE \$REMOTE"

git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode true
```