# Cannot use `git mergetool` with `git am` or `git apply` or `patch`

Tags: git-merge, patch, mergetool, git-apply, git-am

`git mergetool` is wonderful (in my case, I use kdiff3). However, it is not possible to use it to resolve conflicts from `git am` or `git apply` (or even with `patch` command). Indeed, mergetool need 3 files to work (base and both modified versions) while `git am` work with a modified version and a patch.

Do you know a way to use `git mergetool` for conflicts produced with `git am`?

I think it is necessary to guess the base file from modified version and patch. If you consider each chunk separately, it looks tricky, but not impossible.

Comment: `git mergetool` should work if you've hit a three-way merge conflict.  `git am` runs `git apply --3way`, which uses the `index` lines in `git diff` output to locate or reconstruct (when possible) the three objects. If you're finding patches that don't apply and have missing or wrong or inadequate `index` lines, there's nothing you can do here. Well, nothing three-way-ish: you *can* use `git apply --reject` and then hand-massage the rejected bits in an editor, the way we used to do all of this back in the bad old days...

Answer (score 3):

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions, [`git mergetool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool) will be involved if you are:

- doing a [`git am --3way`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am#git-am--3)
- doing a regular git am, but with the [config `am.threeWay`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-amthreeWay) set to true.

The issue remains for a regular patch command.